# python - str containing whitespace characters and int(str)

Tags: python, string-literals

I'm trying to write a really simple function. It should return True if given object is a digit (0-9), False otherwise. Here are examples of input and desired output:

```
is_digit("") => False
is_digit("7") => True
is_digit(" ") => False
is_digit("a") => False
is_digit("a5") => False
```

My code works for the above examples.

```
def is_digit(n):
    try: 
        return int(n) in range(0, 10)
    except:
        return False
```

Trouble is, the function returns True for `n = "1\n"` when it should return False. So, a string like "1" should be converted to integer and is a digit, but a string like "1\n" should not, yet I don't know how to get around that. How can I account for string literals?

P.S. If my title is lame, advice on renaming it is welcome.

Comment: Uhm… are you trying to reinvent `str.isdigit`?

Comment: Are you kidding me :(

Comment: Thanks, I'll delete my question now... EDIT: actually, out of curiosity, is there a way I *could* check if a string contains whitespace characters?

Comment: another possible title: how to parse int from a string value in Python

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor Strings are made from string literals or what do you mean?

Comment: 2 ways to check if string has alphanumeric characters (if I'm understanding correctly): use regex and match on a not digit condition, or check each character in the string individually to see if it's a number or not.

Comment: `my_digit in '1234567890'`

Comment: Thanks guys. What I meant was, how can I check if a string contains whitespace characters?

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor You may use `if bool(re.search('\s', string)):`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define a custom function for this. There is a built-in function for this, namely `isdigit()`.

You can use it as: `"a5".isdigit()` or `"1/n".isdigit()`.In both cases it will return False.

Comment: `"123".isdigit()` also returns `True`. I don't think this is the behavior OP wants. You'd have to do `n.isdigit() and len(n)==1` to get the same behavior as the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert your literals into string then you can apply isdigit. 
You can not apply isdigit directly to number. It will throw an error

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

You have to typecast your number in string.
eg:

```
In [3]: str(0).isdigit()
Out[3]: True
```

or

```
In [1]: "0".isdigit()
Out[1]: True
```